# What's wrong with this code? it's not showing the first row in PrintPreview

Tags: vb.net, print-preview

the code below was actually copied from one of the stackoverflow answers, it's not showing the first row in print preview. Its skipping the first row and shwing starting from second.

here's the code,

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    newpage = True
    With dgvData
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        'Dim fmt2 As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        'Dim font As Font

        'font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", "13", FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Inch, gdiCharSet:=1)
        'fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim rc1 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(460, 20, 350, 20)
        Dim rc2 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(500, 40, 350, 20)

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Some Heading", .Font, Brushes.Black, rc1, fmt)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Another heading ", .Font, Brushes.Black, rc2, fmt)

        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top + 60
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                Dim rc As RectangleF = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                If (newpage) Then
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString)
                Else
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).ToString)
                End If
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            newpage = False
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If I'm understanding this correctly,] It skips the first line because `newpage` is set to True, so when you get to this code:

```
If (newpage) Then
    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
    'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString)
Else
    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
    'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).ToString)
End If
```

you are printing a header, instead of the cell in the current line (`Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)`).

**Edit** in response to "*So should I set the newage = false at start, or is there anything else I should do?*"

If `newpage` evaluates to True, you need to output BOTH the header and the current line. In the original code you are using an `If` switch to do one or the other (thus skipping output of the current line). I did some quick reorganizing, and below is my new suggested code in its entirety, so you can compare.

```
Dim mRow As Integer = 0
Dim newpage As Boolean = True
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    newpage = True
    With dgvData
        Dim fmt As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        'Dim fmt2 As StringFormat = New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.LineLimit)
        fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        'Dim font As Font

        'font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", "13", FontStyle.Underline, GraphicsUnit.Inch, gdiCharSet:=1)
        'fmt.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter
        Dim rc1 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(460, 20, 350, 20)
        Dim rc2 As RectangleF = New RectangleF(500, 40, 350, 20)

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Some Heading", .Font, Brushes.Black, rc1, fmt)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Another heading ", .Font, Brushes.Black, rc2, fmt)

        Dim rc As RectangleF
        Dim y As Single = e.MarginBounds.Top + 60
        Do While mRow < .RowCount
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .Rows(mRow)
            Dim x As Single = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim h As Single = 0
            If (newpage) Then
                For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    rc = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString, .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                    'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Columns(cell.ColumnIndex).HeaderText.ToString)
                    x += rc.Width
                    h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
                Next
                newpage = False
                y += h
                x = e.MarginBounds.Left
                h = 0
            End If
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                rc = New RectangleF(x, y, cell.Size.Width, cell.Size.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rc.Left, rc.Top, rc.Width, rc.Height)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).FormattedValue.ToString(), .Font, Brushes.Black, rc, fmt)
                'MessageBox.Show(dgvData.Rows(cell.RowIndex).ToString)
                x += rc.Width
                h = Math.Max(h, rc.Height)
            Next
            y += h
            mRow += 1
            If y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom Then
                e.HasMorePages = True
                mRow -= 1
                newpage = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Loop
        mRow = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Some of the changes to note:

- The `newpage` switch is segregated from the `For Each` that outputs the actual cells. This causes the current row to be output regardless of the `newpage` condition.
- Some variables (`x`, `h`, and `y`) have to be incremented or modified both inside the switch as well as outside, so those lines are now duplicated.
- The declaration of `rc` was moved outside the `Do While` loop. There's no need to declare it for every cell; instead just assign a new value.
- There's really no need to check `y + h > e.MarginBounds.Bottom` more than once (unless you're printing REALLY BIG), as you can assume that you're only ever printing more than one line if you're already at the top of a new page, so it stays by itself at the end of the loop.
- When you evaluate `Math.Max(h, rc.Height)`, `h` is always zero or equal to rc.Height, so you might consider rethinking this.

Comment: So should I set the newage = false at start, or is there anything else I should do?

Comment: @YiiFighter - I've edited my answer. The value of `newpage` is not the issue, it's that you're forgoing the standard output of the current row for a header if `newpage` is True.

Comment: but the `last row` of the `first page` gets printed as the `first row` (after the header) of the `next page`. what must be the error?

Comment: Try removing `mRow -= 1` inside the `If` statement at the bottom of the code.